# Underwater in unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class underWater : MonoBehaviour {
    public float uwaterLevel=15f;
    public Color normalColor;
    public Color underWaterColor;



    void Start () {
        normalColor = new Color (0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);
        underWaterColor = new Color (0.22f,0.65f,0.77f,0.5f);

    }


    void Update () {
        Debug.Log (uwaterLevel);
        Debug.Log (transform.position.y);
        if(Camera.main.transform.position.y<uwaterLevel){
            Debug.Log("Underwater Update");
            setUnderWater();
        }else{
            Debug.Log("Normal Update");
            setNormal();
        }

    }
    public void setUnderWater(){
        Debug.Log("Under Water");
        RenderSettings.fog = true;
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.05f;
        RenderSettings.fogColor = underWaterColor;

    }
    public void setNormal(){
        Debug.Log("Normal");
        RenderSettings.fog = true;
        RenderSettings.fog = false;
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.003f;
        RenderSettings.fogColor = normalColor;

    }
}
```

How can I detect if my character is under water? Water is above the ground(a lake between the hills) so I can't use negative Y-axis. I'm using FPSController from Unity Standard Assests.

Answer (score 1):

Make a large `Collider` the size of the water. Make it a trigger. Make it's tag `"Water"`

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if(col.tag == "Water")
    {
        // In water
    }
}

public void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if(col.tag == "Water")
    {
        // In water
    }
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    if(col.tag == "Water")
    {
        // Exit water
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer rather than a comment since I can't comment yet.

Similar to what Andrew said, to prevent your game from thinking you're underwater as soon as your character puts its foot in the water, You could add an empty gameobject a few centimeters above your character's head and put a collider on that.

Then use Andrew's logic to determine that your character is underwater.